# Doc to PDF converted file has no data(Used apache POI api)

Tags: java, apache-poi, converters, xwpf

I created a doc file using Apache POI api, and tried to convert to PDF using Apache POI in java. The generated PDF file has no data, but file opened properly. I don't get any Exception while converting.

[Apache api created Doc file](https://cloudinary.com/console/media_library#/dialog/raw/upload/TestDoc_fg9krw.docx)

[Converted PDF File](https://cloudinary.com/console/media_library#/dialog/raw/upload/xxx_i461gw.pdf)

Comment: How are you generating the PDF? What code are you using?

Comment: Don't hide your documents behind services which need a login.